java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStore;
After I returned to an older project, after editing a few things, and updating dependencies, I tried to compile and I keep getting this error on startup:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.parsons.bakery, PID: 7383

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStore;Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider$Factory;)V in class Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider' appears in /data/app/~~N-cXo7nNU-D-YF78BsrFiA==/com.parsons.bakery-FmBA96FlD6t9sILcrQfjgw==/base.apk)

at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel.getInstance(FragmentManagerViewModel.java:52)

at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2703)

at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:117)

at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.lambda$init$3$androidx-fragment-app-FragmentActivity(FragmentActivity.java:139)

at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onContextAvailable(Unknown Source:2)

at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable(ContextAwareHelper.kt:84)

at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:358)

at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:216)

at com.parsons.bakery.Loading.onCreate(Loading.java:14)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)

at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)

at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)

at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

This seems to be an issue in the dependencies as far as I can see, but I'm not confident.
My Gradle file looks as such:
build.gradle

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parsons.bakery"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexKeepProguard = file('multidex-config.pro')
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    //namespace '${namespaceId}'
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile).tap {
            configureEach {
                options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.17.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:25.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

The error and crash start when the launcher class starts:
public class Loading extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView currentActions;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //Error when this is hit
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
...

I've looked through a lot of other people's posts about similar issues, and none seem to work. I've updated dependencies, and rolled some back, invalidated caches/restart, changed the proguard-rules.pro file to keep the androidx.lifecycle.* class members, and allow code and resource shrinking. According to the documentation about the appcompat package, it requires activity 1.7.0 and fragment 1.5.4 as well, but after adding these, it still crashes with the same error.

For Anyone that might have a similar issue:
After working with the Gradle some more- I figured I'd start removing some dependencies that aren't needed. These 2 dependencies seemed to be the issue:
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.1'

As far as I can tell, if you declare them yourself, it overrides automatic dependencies that other packages needed, and thus couldn't find the required methods.
